# installing qwt with qt creator

Tags: ubuntu, qt-creator, qwt

hi every one i have installed qt-creator from built in ubuntu software center now i want to install qwt i have download qw1-6.0-rc5 from a site unzip it it contain many files like
qwt.prf qwt.pro qtbuilt,pri. i dnt know what all this mean kindly help me installing qwt do i have run these file or simply include them i my program .if i have to run them what is the command to install in which folder i have to place the for installing

thanks

kindly help me waiting for a reply

i am using ubuntu 10.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure for installing it is detailed on the [Qwt User's Guide: INSTALL page](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/qwtinstall.html).  The basic summary is to unpack the files and then at a shell prompt issue the commands

```
qmake
make
sudo make install
```